# OpenLDAP and SVN on MAC OS X without Kerberos

Tags: apache, svn, kerberos, openldap

I all!
I have a **SVN server** (running on MAC OS X Captain). I have also configured **OpenLDAP,** so that when users access the SVN server with a userName and Password, they access SVN repositories upon success (w.r.t openLDAP database entries).

However, when users try to log in to the SVN authentication fails. I run sldap in debug mode to figure out what is going wrong. I found out that user&pass match LDAP database entries. However, what I additionally found is that it **tries to authenticate users with Kerberos.** I only want SVN & LDAP. Anyone knows **how can I disable Kerberos attempting to authenticate?**
Thanks in advance! 
Leticia

**httpd.config snipped (apache 2.4):**

```
<Location /svn/Thesis>
DAV svn
SVNPath /var/svn/repositories/Thesis
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Repository"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=org"
AuthLDAPBindPassword pasword1
AuthLDAPURL ldap://158.227.115.33:389/dc=company,dc=org?cn?sub?(objectclass=*)
Require ldap-group cn=ActiveMember,ou=Groups,o=company,dc=company,dc=org
</Location>
```

**Slap.conf**

```
include         /private/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /private/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /private/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /private/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /private/etc/openldap/schema/samba.schema

modulepath      /usr/libexec/openldap
moduleload      back_bdb.la

# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!
access to dn.subtree="o=company,dc=company,dc=org"
    by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=org" write
    by self write
    by users read
    by anonymous auth
access to *
by self write
    by users read
    by anonymous auth

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=company,dc=org"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=org"
rootpw          {SSHA}dr/1Yu+mRLm6PAHtp+UMqJuJMlMMTFQd
directory       /private/var/db/openldap/openldap-data

# Indices to maintain for this database
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname  eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
```

**Ldap.conf**

```
URI ldap://127.0.0.1/
BASE dc=company,dc=org

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never
TLS_REQCERT demand
```

**Log when users try to log in to the SVN (run slapd -d 255)**

```
………
56ec1897 do_bind: version=3 dn="cn=John,ou=Members,o=company,dc=company,dc=org" method=128
56ec1897 ==> bdb_bind: dn: cn=John,ou=Members,o=company,dc=company,dc=org
56ec1897 bdb_dn2entry("cn=John,ou=members,o=company,dc=company,dc=org")
56ec1897 => bdb_search
56ec1897 bdb_dn2entry("cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=company,dc=org")
56ec1897 => bdb_dn2id("cn=config,dc=company,dc=org")
56ec1897 <= bdb_dn2id: get failed: DB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found (-30988)
56ec1897 => access_allowed: disclose access to "dc=company,dc=org" "entry" requested
56ec1897 => dn: [1] o=company,dc=company,dc=org
56ec1897 => acl_get: [2] attr entry
56ec1897 => acl_mask: access to entry "dc=company,dc=org", attr "entry" requested
56ec1897 => acl_mask: to all values by "cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=company,dc=org", (=0) 
56ec1897 <= check a_dn_pat: self
56ec1897 <= check a_dn_pat: users
56ec1897 <= acl_mask: [2] applying read(=rscxd) (stop)
56ec1897 <= acl_mask: [2] mask: read(=rscxd)
56ec1897 => slap_access_allowed: disclose access granted by read(=rscxd)
56ec1897 => access_allowed: disclose access granted by read(=rscxd)
56ec1897 send_ldap_result: conn=-1 op=0 p=0
56ec1897 send_ldap_result: err=10 matched="dc=company,dc=org" text=""
56ec1897 Entry *odusers_copy_entry(Operation *): Unable to locate    cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=company,dc=org (32)
56ec1897 odusers_copy_krbrealm: No entry associated with KerberosKDC cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=company,dc=org
56ec1897 odusers_krb_auth: could not retrieve krb realm while authing John
56ec1897 send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=2 p=3
56ec1897 send_ldap_result: err=50 matched="" text=""
56ec1897 send_ldap_response: msgid=3 tag=97 err=50
…….
```

Comment: If you have Kerberos in place and working, don't waste your time and use it. I can tell you how.

Comment: `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on` ???

Comment: Note also http://serverfault.com/questions/437434/apache-httpd-ldap-integration (in short - `Require ldap-group` doesn't work with SVN... may be outdated data)

Comment: @Lazy Badger "AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on" is no longer supported in apache 2.4. What should I use instead?

Comment: @Michael-O How hard is it to set up Kerberos authorization? I'm a newbie ;) Can I keep in sync LDAP data and Kerberos data?

Comment: @leti88, it takes less than a day with all checks. What exactly do you want to keep synchronized?

Comment: @Michael-O, Basically, we have usernames and passwords, which we use to access a SVN server. I guess i need to have those in Kerberos, right?

Comment: @leti88. Yes, all authentication is performed by Kerberos only. I will publish my documentation today or tomorrow on the net.

Comment: Thank you very much  @Michael-O :-) Have a nice day

Comment: @leti88 Check out https://s.apache.org/svn-enterprise-auth tomorrow or Wednesday.

Comment: @leti88 The documentation is now online. Have a look please.

Comment: @Michael-O GREAT! Thanks

Comment: @leti88. Feel free to contact me, I'd like to hear your results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I finally solved it!

Apparently if LDAP backend is bdb, Kerberos is automatically called (don't know exactly how/why). However, when I change it to ldif, there aren't any calls to Kerberos, and everything works as expected. The steps I performed are as follows:

1. Using Apache directory Studio LDAP browser, I exported my DIT to a ldif file.
2. I stopped slapd, and changed line "database bdb" to "database ldif" (in slap.conf). I also removed all the files from the db directory, except DATABASE_CONFIG.
3. I started slapd, and again, using the Apache directory studio I imported the ldif file previously created  (in step 1).
4. voilà :-)